# Capture event when shape is inserted in Microsoft Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, office-addins

I am creating a document and need to execute an action after a shape was automatically inserted in the header of a document by another add-in. The event ContentControlAfterAdd of the Document object does not fire, when a shape is inserted.
Is there any way, to capture insertion of a shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such event. Shapes have nothing to do with Content Controls.